# I want to convert excel data into multiple Json in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, excel, typescript

My Excel has many data table which i want to convert it into a Json in javascript/typescript. Following are the sample of my excel data in one sheet separated by one or more empty rows.

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| John | 40 |
| Olivia | 30 |

| EmpId | Salary | LanguagesKnown |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43567 | 15000 | English,French |
| 98543 | 20000 | Arab,Chinese |

I want to convert these into Json.

Expected output:

```
**Json for first table:**

{
"Name" : "John",
"Age" : 40
}

{
"Name" : "Olivia",
"Age" : 30
}

**Json for Second Table:**

{
"EmpId" : 43567,
"Salary" : 15000,
"LanguagesKnown" : ["English","French"]
}

{
"EmpId" : 98543,
"Salary" : 20000,
"LanguagesKnown" : ["Arab","Chinese"]
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know how to read the excel data to map (using apache poi) and then convert into POJO class in java. But i don't know how to do in javascript. And i know this isn't Fiverr. I thought people would give solution/pointer here.

Comment: You provided no code which gives the impression that you expect us to create an entire solution to your specification. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Posting on stack overflow should always be the [very *last* thing you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Did you, for instance, try googling excel libraries for node.js? If so, why didn't you include that in the question? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have included code as well. The main issue is all node.js libraries like sheetJs or other utlis converts the whole sheet into json. but my problem is converting a part of excel into json. I am new to javascript which has a object similar to json. So i thought there could be a easy way rather converting the excel to map and constructing json by using POJO in java.

Answer (score 0):

[js-xlsx](https://github.com/protobi/js-xlsx/tree/beta#readme) library can convert Excel/CSV files into JSON objects.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.6/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        var url = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_10.xls"; //Excel File
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.open("GET", url, true);
        oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

        oReq.onload = function(e) {
            var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

            /* convert to binary */
            var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
            var arr = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            var bstr = arr.join("");

            var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
                type: "binary"
            });

            var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0]; //Excel sheet No
            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
            const convertToJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
                raw: true
            })
            console.log(convertToJson);
        }

        oReq.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
Output:

```
[
    {
        "0": 1,
        "First Name": "Dulce",
        "Last Name": "Abril",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "United States",
        "Age": 32,
        "Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Id": 1562
    },
    {
        "0": 2,
        "First Name": "Mara",
        "Last Name": "Hashimoto",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "Great Britain",
        "Age": 25,
        "Date": "16/08/2016",
        "Id": 1582
    },
    {
        "0": 3,
        "First Name": "Philip",
        "Last Name": "Gent",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Country": "France",
        "Age": 36,
        "Date": "21/05/2015",
        "Id": 2587
    },
    {
        "0": 4,
        "First Name": "Kathleen",
        "Last Name": "Hanner",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "United States",
        "Age": 25,
        "Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Id": 3549
    },
    {
        "0": 5,
        "First Name": "Nereida",
        "Last Name": "Magwood",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "United States",
        "Age": 58,
        "Date": "16/08/2016",
        "Id": 2468
    },
    {
        "0": 6,
        "First Name": "Gaston",
        "Last Name": "Brumm",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Country": "United States",
        "Age": 24,
        "Date": "21/05/2015",
        "Id": 2554
    },
    {
        "0": 7,
        "First Name": "Etta",
        "Last Name": "Hurn",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "Great Britain",
        "Age": 56,
        "Date": "15/10/2017",
        "Id": 3598
    },
    {
        "0": 8,
        "First Name": "Earlean",
        "Last Name": "Melgar",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "United States",
        "Age": 27,
        "Date": "16/08/2016",
        "Id": 2456
    },
    {
        "0": 9,
        "First Name": "Vincenza",
        "Last Name": "Weiland",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "United States",
        "Age": 40,
        "Date": "21/05/2015",
        "Id": 6548
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I make use of [async-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-csv) package

```
import * as fs from "fs";
import csv from 'async-csv';

const fsInstance = fs.promises;

const csvString = await fsInstance.readFile(mailListFound.mailListPath, 'utf-8');
const rows = await csv.parse(csvString);
rows.shift();
const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
```

The data inside the data variable is now a JSON that you can use.
Notes: I used the rows.shift() to remove the header row from my data before parsing it with JSON.parse.

My sample file looks like this
[image]